# VBA pull string from the file path

Tags: vba, string

Looking help - a way to pull the string from the filename and perform a task using the string part of the formula manually.
Right now I can pull the file from the folder and use the string part of my program

```
C:\ XXXX_555_GGGGG.xlsx  ( extraxt '555")

C:\ XXXX_101_GGGGG.xlsx  (extraxt"101")

....cont!
```

manually we can do this for each of the files:

```vb
Sub Combined()
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b2").Value = _
         Application.SumIfs(Sheet1.Columns(2), Sheet1.Columns(1), "555")
End Sub


Sub Combined1()
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b3").Value = _
         Application.SumIfs(Sheet1.Columns(2), Sheet1.Columns(1), "101")

End Sub
```

Looking for a better way to automated this:

- Open the folder
- pull the string from filename path ( file one) ( i.e '555')
- use the string part of my sum formula
- next file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dir()` to loop over files in a folder

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim c As Range, f, arr, wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or whatever
    Set c = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
    
    f = Dir("C:\FolderTest\*.xlsx")
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        arr = Split(f, "_")
        If UBound(arr) = 2 Then 'check file pattern
            c.Value = Application.SumIfs(Sheet1.Columns(2), Sheet1.Columns(1), arr(1))
            Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        f = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```